# Idiom for a C++11 enum with methods and static instances?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

I'd like to do the following (which won't compile):

```
class Foo {
    int value;

    Foo(const int arg)
        : value{arg}
    {}

public:    
    static const Foo a{0};
    static const Foo b{1};
    static const Foo c{2};

    Foo func(const Foo& foo) {...}
};
```

so that the the instances of `Foo` are strongly controlled (like in an `enum`) and so that I can write code like `auto foo = Foo::a;` and `auto foo = Foo::a.func(Foo::b);`

Unfortunately, the code won't compile under C++11 because the static instances have incomplete type.

Is there an idiom for this?

Comment: In C++11 `static` members must be defined separately. In your class `static const Foo b;`, in your .cpp `Foo const Foo::b = 1;`. Alternatively C++17 adds a new meaning for `inline` which let's you write `static inline const Foo b{1};` in a `class` without needing a separate definition.

Comment: It's not possible, you can't create an instance (an object) of a class until the class have been fully defined (which it is with the closing `}`). Perhaps if you explain the actual problem you try to solve with this, and explain why you cant use enumerations (the "classic" or the C++11 strongly typed variant) we might able to help you with that instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it quite easily but you need to put the definitions of your constants outside the class:

```cpp
class Foo {
    int value;

    // In C++17, you could make this constexpr.
    Foo(const int arg)
        : value{arg}
    {}

public:
    // in C++20, you could make these constinit.
    static const Foo a;
    static const Foo b;
    static const Foo c;
};

// In C++11 these need to go in the source file to avoid linker errors.
// In C++17 you could make them inline and put them in the header.
// In C++20 you could make them constinit.
const Foo Foo::a = 0;
const Foo Foo::b = 1;
const Foo Foo::c = 2;
```

I wouldn't call this an elegant solution though. Particularly in C++11, these constants can't be inlined by the compiler because they need to go into the source file. This can have a significant impact on performance. So if you're going to do it, I would recommend using at least C++17, if not C++20.

Generally, C++ enums are meant to be integer constants and there is no support for getting the ordinal or name of an `enum` like there is in Java. An alternative approach is to use an `enum class` with no values (which defaults to values 0, 1, 2, ...) and then use them as indices inside of lookup tables.

Using a `switch` for properties can also do the trick:

```cpp
enum class Axis : unsigned { X, Y, Z };

// in C++17, you could make this constexpr.
inline const char *nameOf(Axis axis)
{
    switch (axis) {
    case Axis::X: return "X";
    case Axis::Y: return "Y";
    case Axis::Z: return "Z";
    }
}
```